# Query is returning to rows instead of just one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a a query to return the dimensions of a package in M2 (square metres) and UN (unity's). With the current query it is returning two different lines, because I am using a `CASE WHEN`. This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(C.Package) 'Package',
    CASE S.Unity WHEN 'M2' THEN SUM(L.Qt*S.ConvEst) ELSE NULL END 'M2',
    CASE S.Unity WHEN 'UN' THEN SUM(L.Qt) ELSE NULL END 'UN'
FROM 
    PackageTable AS C
INNER JOIN 
    PackageTableRows L ON L.Package = C.Package
INNER JOIN 
    Products S ON S.Product = L.Product
WHERE 
    C.Package = '587496'
GROUP BY 
    C.Package, S.Unity
```

This result:

[image]

But what I really want is the query to return is something like this:

[image]

With only one line. I know for that I am not using `CASE WHEN` correctly and that is why I need your help.

Comment: Why you change the question after Larnu provided an answer explaining what is wrong with your query? Now the first part of his answer is invalidated

Comment: The OP edited after I made a comment about the `DISTINCT` rather than the answer, @TimSchmelter , though I didn't notice that they had removed said part till *after* I had both written and submitted the answer. (I have since deleted said comments, because I expanded on them in my answer.) I have rolled back said edit though, as you're right that it invalidates the answer; generally it is frowned upon to change such things after you've started getting answers/comments on your code, Forrobodo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here. Firstly, `DISTINCT` is *not* a function it's an operator. `DISTINCT` affects the *entire* dataset and causes only *distinct* rows to be returned. It's not `DISTINCT ({Column Name})` it's `SELECT DISTINCT {Columns}`.

Next, you have *both* `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`; this is a flaw. A `GROUP BY` clause already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* groups, so a `DISTINCT` is both redundant and unneeded overhead. Get rid of the `DISTINCT`. If you *are* getting different results when you have a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` this is a strong indication that your `GROUP BY` clause is wrong and needs addressing (most likely you have too many columns in the clause).

Finally, when performing conditional aggregation the aggregate function should be around the *entire* `CASE` expression, not an expression in the `THEN`. Then also means that you then need to remove the column in your `WHEN` clause from the `GROUP BY` as I suspect the only reason you have it there is because you *had* to:

This results in:

```sql
SELECT C.Package AS Package,
       SUM(CASE S.Unity WHEN 'M2' THEN L.Qt * S.ConvEst END) AS M2,
       SUM(CASE S.Unity WHEN 'UN' THEN L.Qt END) AS UN
FROM dbo.PackageTable C
     INNER JOIN dbo.PackageTableRows L ON L.Package = C.Package
     INNER JOIN dbo.Products S ON S.Product = L.Product
WHERE C.Package = '587496'
GROUP BY C.Package;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your help. Now I learned a little bit more about SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly correct. You need to GROUP BY only on C.Package to bring it into a single line. For this it should return 0 for case else conditions and aggregation should be on the full case conditions rather than only on the measure.

So it will look like this.

```
SELECT C.Package 'Package',
SUM(CASE S.Unity WHEN 'M2' THEN (L.Qt*S.ConvEst) ELSE 0 END ) as 'M2', 
SUM(CASE S.Unity WHEN 'UN' THEN SL.Qt ELSE 0 END) AS 'UN'
FROM PackageTable AS C
INNER JOIN PackageTableRows L ON L.Package=C.Package
INNER JOIN Products S ON S.Product=L.Product
WHERE C.Package='587496'
GROUP BY C.Package
```